ggplot2: Make points align with actual date when date is a factor
I made a time series that has a discontinuous x-axis however, I only know how to make these kinds of plots when the x-axis Date is a factor. The issue this causes is that the points in the plot align with the factor suggesting that the points are collected on the first of the month which is not true. Is there any way to align the points with the actual Date while maintaining the discontinuous x-axis?
Example
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)

set.seed(333)

# Create example dataset
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'),
  Date = rep(c('2021-07-13','2021-08-22','2021-09-04','2022-06-20','2022-07-08','2022-08-25'), 2),
  Value = round(rnorm(12,50,20)))

# Do some data wrangling
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         year = year(Date),
         mon = month(Date),
         mon_abb = month.abb[mon],
         monYear = paste(mon_abb,year, sep = ' ')) %>%
  select(!c(mon,year,mon_abb))

# Will need the month abbreviation
sample_dates <- unique(df$monYear)

# Make figure
# Note: the points align on the month but I would like them to
# align with the actual calendar Date (i.e., all points would move
# to the right because none were collected on the 1st of the month)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Value, group = Group)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Group), size = 3, shape = 21, color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = substr(sample_dates, 1, 3)) + # Pulls the month abb. for x-axis label
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 1), "lines"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = 'right',
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  annotation_custom(rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA))) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 2, y = -16, label = 2021, size = 4.5) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 5, y = -16, label = 2022, size = 4.5) +
  annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 3.4, xmax = 3.6, ymin = -10, ymax = -3, fill = 'white') +
  annotate(geom = 'segment', x = c(3.4,3.6), xend = c(3.4,3.6), y = -8, yend = -3)


Created on 2024-04-04 with reprex v2.0.2

I think the ggbreak package deals with breaks on a continuous axis.

You could do this with facet_grid(scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") so that the points are proportionately spaced across facets.
ggplot(data = df |> mutate(era = +(Date > as.Date("2022-06-01"))), 
       aes(x = Date, y = Value, group = Group)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Group), size = 3, shape = 21, color = "black") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b\n%Y", 
               minor_breaks = NULL, expand = expansion(add = 31)) +
  # scale_x_discrete(labels = substr(sample_dates, 1, 3)) + # Pulls the month abb. for x-axis label
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 1), "lines"),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0),
        legend.position = 'right',
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  facet_grid(.~era, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', ylim = c(0, 100)) 


Alternatively, we could convert the dates to numeric + adjustment, which if we've already established a discrete x axis (with a transparent layer like your existing one), will get placed on that:
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Value, group = Group)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Group), alpha = 0) + # hidden, to get axis labels
  geom_point(aes(fill = Group, 
               x = as.numeric(factor(Date)) + (day(Date)-1)/ days_in_month(Date)), 
             size = 3, shape = 21, color = "black") +
  ...



Hmm, I don't get that error, running tidyverse 2.0.0. I presume that's related to how df is also an R function, so sometimes a troublesome table name. You could try moving the era calculation into your earlier wrangling (df <- df %>% ...).

I was being dumb, your script works. The second (bottom) answer you provided is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

I've added another approach that is more of a hack around your existing code, keeping the discrete labels but placing a numeric-spaced layer on it.
